# Var dumping a JSON object with laravel with JSON Formatter

Tags: json, google-chrome, laravel, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to figure why I whenI browse to a page that has JSON data it won't display it in the JSON formatter with the jSON Formatter plugin installed on my local computer. Anybody know why this could be the issue? What are some possibilities for me to look into?

```
/**
 * Display a listing of users
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    // Retrieve all users from database with roles and statuses
    //$users = User::with('role')->with('status')->get();
    $users = User::all();

    var_dump($users);

    // Return a view to display all users by passing users variable to view.
    //return View::make('users.index', compact('users'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the tool your post mentions, but when you say

```
    var_dump($users);
```

you're not returning JSON.  You're returning an HTML page that contains text contents that looks like dumped JSON.

I'm going to guess that the "jSON Formatter" plugin you mentioned looks for property JSON response headers to decide if it should handle a request or not.  Try the following instead.

```
public function index()
{
    // Retrieve all users from database with roles and statuses
    //$users = User::with('role')->with('status')->get();
    $users = User::all();

    return Response::json($users);
}
```

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa is a good Chrome extension you can use that will format JSON even if it it's being sent as JSON.